# Equivalent Orlicz Norm?

Tags: normed-spaces, orlicz-spaces

An equivalent norm for Orlicz spaces is the Luxemburg norm, defined on $L\Phi$ by
$$ 
\|f\|'_{\Phi }=\inf \left\{k\in (0,\infty )\left| \int _{X}\Phi \left(\frac{|f|}{k}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right.\leq 1\right\}
$$
as it can be seen in the [relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlicz_space).
Moreover, in the particular case of Sobolev Spaces, the norm can be given the structure of an integral. Recall that more precisely, Orlicz spaces generalize $L^p$ spaces (for
$1<p<\infty)$ in the sense that if
$ \Phi (t)=t^{p}$ the above norm reduces to the one for these spaces given by $\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}:= \left(\int_\Omega |f|^p \right)^{1/p}dx$

I am wondering if there is an equivalent Orlicz norm given by an integral so that we do not need use the concept of infimum.

Precisely I'd prefer a norm given, for example, by the following expression as it is more manageable
$$
\|f\|_{\Phi }=\sup \left\{\|fg\|_{1}\left| \int \Psi \circ |g|\,\mathrm{d}\mu \right.\leq 1\right\}.
$$
My question is motivated by the fact that by Lemma 2.3 in the paper "[A minimum problem with free boundary in Orlicz spaces](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2008.03.028)" by Sandra Martínez and Noemi Wolanski we have
$$
 \|u\|_{G} \le C \max \left\{\left(\int_{\Omega} G(|u|) \mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac{1}{g_0+1}}, \left(\int_{\Omega} G(|u|) \mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac{1}{g_1+1}} \right\}.
 $$
So, I was wondering if in the case that
that
$$  0 < g_0 \le \frac{t \cdot g'(t)}{g(t)} \le g_1 \quad \forall \, t >0.
$$
the right hand side can be thought as a somewhat equivalent norm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an equivalent Orlicz norm exactly with the structure that you required, with the function $\Psi$ being

$$\Phi^*(t):=\sup_{s \in \mathbb{R}} \{st-\Phi(s)\}$$

i.e. the convex coniugate of $\Phi$. Indeed, if we set
$$\|f\|_\Phi:=\sup \{\|fg\|_1: \int \Phi^*(|g|) d\mu \leq 1\}$$
then $\|f\|’_\Phi \leq \|f\|_\Phi \leq 2\|f\|’_\Phi$. For the proof see [this note](https://leonard.perso.math.cnrs.fr/papers/Leonard-Orlicz%20spaces.pdf) (the second inequality follows from a variant of Holder’s inequality, while the first one is more delicate).